# How to change the default color scheme of Seurat Dimplot?

Tags: r, seurat

Dear experts worldwide,

Hello,
I am using Seurat to analyze integrated single-cell RNA-seq data.
I confirmed the default color scheme of Dimplot like the described below.

```r
show_col(hue_pal()(16))
```

[image]

But I wanted to change the current default colors of Dimplot.
So, I tried it by the comment below. It successfully changed colors in Dimplot, but this changed color palette is not applied to downstream analysis (such as cluster labeling bar in DoHeatmap..).

```r
DimPlot(object = Integrateddata, reduction = 'umap',
  group.by = 'seurat_clusters', pt.size = 1, label=FALSE,
  cols = c('0'='#F68282','4'='#31C53F','8'='#1FA195','6'='#B95FBB','3'='#D4D915',
    '7'='#28CECA','1'='#ff9a36','2'='#2FF18B','10'='#aeadb3','11'='#faf4cf',
    '5'='#CCB1F1','9'='#25aff5','12'='#A4DFF2','15'='#4B4BF7','13'='#AC8F14',
    '14'='#E6C122'))
```

Is there any way to change the default color scheme of Dimplot and apply it to all the downstream analysis?

Thanks!

Comment: you can consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be `DimPlot(cols=)` relies on the names in the named character vector of colors, whereas `DoHeatmap(group.colors=)` relies on their order. So you just need to order them by name, and the color scheme should be consistent:

```
my_seurat <- subset(initial_object, idents = 1:16)

levels(Idents(my_seurat))

my_cols <- c('3'='#F68282','15'='#31C53F','5'='#1FA195','1'='#B95FBB','13'='#D4D915',
  '14'='#28CECA','9'='#ff9a36','8'='#2FF18B','11'='#aeadb3','6'='#faf4cf',
  '2'='#CCB1F1','12'='#25aff5','7'='#A4DFF2','4'='#4B4BF7','16'='#AC8F14',
  '10'='#E6C122')

my_cols2 <- my_cols[order(as.integer(names(my_cols)))]
scales::show_col(my_cols2)


DimPlot(my_seurat,
        cols = my_cols2, label=TRUE , repel=TRUE)
DoHeatmap(my_seurat,
          features = c("gene1", "gene2"),
          group.colors = my_cols2)
```